# html is blank in a blackberry cascades webview (C++, QT, QML)

Tags: html, webview, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

in Blackberry Cascades (C++, QT, QML), I am trying to read the html of a webview - but it is returning blank. This webview uses "setUrl(url") to set the url, and does not use "setHtml(html)".  Anyway - I have this code:

```
WebView {
    id: loginView
    objectName: "loginView"
    onMicroFocusChanged: {
        console.log("html: " + html);
    }
}
```

And the webview url has two textfields, and when I put my cursor into those text fields or when I type in them, the html of the webview shows up as blank - but I need to see the html, because I am trying to be able to parse that html to get the content of those textfields.

How come the html is blank - and how can I get access to this html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Html property of the WebView only returns the code that was inserted with setHtml. [(Documentation)](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#property-html)
Even if it did report code loaded from a web address, I doubt it would be updated with the current value of textboxes.

To read their content, I recommend you look into the [messageReceived](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#function-messagereceived-message) signal of the WebView. If you can change the html-code that contains your text boxes, you can use javascript `navigator.cascades.postMessage()` to send the data to your application.

If you do not control the html, you can still use the [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#function-evaluatejavascript-script-world) method to extract the values of the textboxes with DOM functions from inside your app.